# Cannot drop, edit, retrieve data from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have created table in SQL Server 2012 which has a column of type `decimal(18, 4)`.

I changed that decimal column to `decimal(30, 14)` and saved the table.

Now I can't do anything with that table. I can't even retrieve rows, edit, insert or drop and recreate that table.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: It doesnt give any error message and take long time to execute a query and finally gives time out exception. If i try to drop and re-create it gives an error message "Invalid Urn filter on server level: filter must be empty, or server attribute must be equal with the true server name. "

Comment: can you access other tables?

Comment: Is this your local database (on your own computer) or a remote server?

Comment: The definition could be corrupt. Stop and re-start SQL server.  Close SSMS and get back in.

Comment: Run a select statement against that table and in another session run sp_who2. If on the spid of the select statement you have any value on the BlkBy column, kill that spid and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Blam . I restarted the service and now working fine